# Is there any way to make this animation's height as tall as my text?

Tags: html, css, text

I have a title in my page which the animation that slides out is only 1/2 of the height of the text, but in half-screen (phone or on split screen), it covers the entire text, this is because my title font-size is based on vw. Is there any way that the animation's height is always as tall as the text, not the entire element? Here is the website -->https://proking73.github.io/P.W.I.L-with_Sis/, and you could check the source code or inspect the page. My goal is that the animation covers the entire text.

Comment: Use your code here as minimum code needed to reproduce the same effect

Comment: What does that mean? (sorry) Could you maybe explain it in more detail?

Comment: The code needed to make the animation on the website you are sharing the link to

Comment: Yes, the animation was made, I need help making it the height the same as the text.

Comment: like this `html` is : `<h1 onclick="jusType();" id="title" style="text-align:center;">Practicing everything I learn,<br><em>restarting /w Aarushi® edition</em></h1>` ; Javascipt : .....................

Comment: Never mind, I just used the same method for the font-size as the height of the animation. Problem solved.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238491/discussion-between-proking73questioneer-and-rana).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, the answer was to just make the height the same as my font size height.